# Relationing a single row of table C for each row of table B of a row in table A

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have `Users`, `Products` and `Buyed` models/tables. Each user can buy multiple products.

How can I retrieve the product name/description from `Users::model()->with->('Buyed')->findByPk(1);`?

If I add another `->with('Products')` Yii will complain about missing `Products` relation in the `Users` model (which I don't have, but I certainly can't insert there, or can I?)

The closest I have achieved to get is by setting this relation in the `Users` model:

```
'Products' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Products', array('idproduct'=>'idproduct'), 'through'=>'Buyed'),
```

But this won't insert the data of each product to the buyed item, but to the user itself. I mean, this way I'd have `$result->Buyed` which would be an array of products that the user has buyed, and `$result->Products`, which will contain all the products's descriptions/names that the user has buyed.

Is it possible to access the data of each product the following way?

```
$result->buyed[<N index>]->product
```

Comment: I suppose that `with->('Buyed')` is a typo, you should check it. At any rate, have you tried something along the lines of `Users::model()->with(array('Buyed'=>array('index'=>'whateverTheIdOfBuyedIsCalled', 'with'=>'Products')))->findByPk(1)` ? I think it should cater to your needs, a simpler version, without the keys of the Buyed array being its id, might be `Users::model()->with('Buyed', 'Buyed.Products')->findByPk(1)`. Hope this helps

Comment: @Chander I just found that I can actually make Yii lazyload the Products by doing `$result->Buyed[0]->Product` and creating a `BELONGS_TO` relation in `Buyed` :)

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to eager load, my bad. Anyways, glad to read; good luck, mate!